# Issues while creating and deploying an app to google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am running into this error while deploying my app to google app-engine.

Error:

Error 404: --- begin server output ---
This application does not exist (project_id=u'homework-153002'). To create an App Engine application in this project, run "gcloud beta app create" in your console.
--- end server output ---

When I try to create the app using the above command this is what I see:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.app.create) You do not have permission to access app [homework] (or it may not exist): Operation not allowed
```

I have created a project in google developers api website with project_name of "homework" and random id. Here is the url for that:
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library?project=homework-153002

Any pointers on what I might be doing wrong here?

This is my yaml file:

```
application: homework-153002
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

Comment: Your application ID is then `homework-153002`, not `homework`, so you need to correct that in your deployment command and/or your `app.yaml` file.

Comment: Same error with updated application ID

Comment: I was able to get this working. Here is the set of commands I had to use:
1) gcloud config set project homework-153002
2) gcloud beta app create
3) appcfg.py update homework/
Thanks @Dan for your suggestion, it helped.

Comment: Glad to hear. I'll make it an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app URL indicates your app ID is `homework-153002`, but the 
error message indicates you're connecting to an ap called `homework`  - likely not your own, hence the permission issue.

Simply correcting the app ID in your deployment command and/or your app.yaml file should suffice.

As your comment indicates, for your case (`gcloud` deployment) the solution was:

```
gcloud config set project homework-153002
gcloud beta app create
appcfg.py update homework/
```