# The "appengine.applications.get" permission is required

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-boot, gcloud, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy my first app engine spring boot project using gradle and I am running into the following error when I run "gradle appengineDeploy":

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [403] Operation not allowed
Details: [
  [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo",
      "description": "The \"appengine.applications.get\" permission is required.",
      "resourceType": "gae.api"
    }
  ]
]
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE")
        classpath("com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:+")
    }
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'
jar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      url 'https://maven-central.storage.googleapis.com'
    }
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    // tag::actuator[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    // end::actuator[]
    // tag::tests[]
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    // end::tests[]
    //compile("com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.0.0")
    //appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.50'
    compile('com.google.appengine:appengine:+')
}
appengine {
  deploy {   // deploy configuration
    stopPreviousVersion = true  // default - stop the current version
    promote = true              // default - & make this the current version
  }
}
```

Please let me know how to proceed.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have rights to deploy to this project. What account owns the project, and what account are you deploying from?

Comment: I am deploying with the same account that owns the project

Comment: If the project Id in your local gcloud configuration does not match the project  Id in console in google cloud, it throws the same error message

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 12):

I got this after updating the google cloud sdk. I just run `gcloud init` again and entered the same choices.

Comment: `gcloud init` is always useful. It also helps to check that the project in the configuration is the project id and not the project name (see also [Issues while creating and deploying an app to google app engine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41234559/2314737))

Answer (score 1):

I recreated the app engine instance and the problem was fixed

Comment: I came to a similar conclusion. I deleted the gcloud config folder (~/.config/gcloud on ubuntu) and reauthenticated and everything works now.

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to fix it other by re-creating the project.

Answer (score 0):

A bit silly, but I got this error by mistyping the GCP project name:

```
$ gcloud app deploy app.yaml --project=wrong-project-name
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by enabling the 'google app engine' cloud api in their api console.